# Error using pip using the cmd in windows even thought PATH variable is set to scripts folder

Tags: python, pip

Trying to use pip to install a package. I've read through all the documentation surrounding this issue. Added the scripts folder to the PATH variable. Pip is still not recognized.

Pip is definitely installed in the scripts folder.

I thought the problem might be me not opening the cmd as an administrator, but that doesn't work either. What might be the problem? Help please

```
C:\windows\system32>pip install sickle
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


C:\windows\system32>echo %PATH%
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v
1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Pro
gram Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime
\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
 SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
 Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:
\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microso
ft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web
 Platform Installer\;C:\Python34; C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Users\Administrator\App
Data\Roaming\npm; C:\Python34\
```

Comment: Just as a sanity check, can you do a `dir` in `c:\Python34\Scripts`?

Comment: Also, that extra space before `C:\Python34\Scripts` looks suspicious

Comment: Did you try making a new command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is definitely your path.

```
C:\Python34; C:\Python34\Scripts
```

The extra space breaks it.